# Page getting loaded multiple times when mod_rewrite enabled (and css missing)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have enabled `mod_rewrite` and am using a `.htaccess` file to pass all requests through `index.php`.

If I visit the URL's

```
http://localhost/mysite

http://localhost/mysite/abc
```

the page loads once.

However, if I add extra parts to the path, the page loads three times and my css files dont get included:

```
http://localhost/mysite/abc/xyz

http://localhost/mysite/abc/xyz/ttt
```

etc...

All cause the page to load three times. I can see this as I have a breakpoint set in `index.php` in **Eclipse**.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. 
  # Files whose names begin with a period are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas why the page is getting loaded multiple times and the css is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe **RewriteRule ^ index.php** is the problem because of the space.

try this instead:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**RewriteRule** pattern substitution flags
pattern: Is requested file index.php
substitution: none (- means do not replace)
flag: L - last **(don't do any more)**

**Condition1**: if the requested file does not exist

**Condition2**: If the requested file is not a directory

Apply next re-write rule
**RewriteRule** pattern substitution flags
pattern: anything
substitution: /index.php
flag: L - last (dont do any more)
IE jump to /index.php

so in summary:
If file requested is index.php OK (and stop processing any more rules)
otherwise
If file exists do it
If file is a directory go into that directory
otherwise
jump to index.php in root web directory

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with the original for the rest of us? Just put it in your answer please.

Comment: @Matt +1 It's all jibber-jabber to me. Waygood, would you be a champion and in plain english for the dumb folk like me, explain what went wrong? +1 in any case *wink wink* but please :)

Comment: This doesn't work. Any path 'bigger' than the base path results in a URL not found error. For example http://localhost/mysite works but http://localhost/mysite/a doesn't work.

Comment: Cheers for the answer mate, I have used a workaround now so this is not an issue for me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add my situation as additional info.
I found this answer also a solution to my problem.

The problem I had was exactly the same. I performed a db insert and I noticed that the entry got inserted a random number of times.

Sometimes 15, sometimes 2 and sometimes 25.

The line I had to change was :

```
RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]
```

**To**

```
RewriteRule    (.*)core/$1    [L]
```

Hence between **(.*) core/$1** is a space
And this should be removed.